# suppressing applications digital certificate has been verified do you want to run this application

Tags: java, digital-signature

I'm new to java and I have a problem very similar to this.. suppress a digital certificate when prompted. I have full control over the environment. Any possible solutions? [Expert Exchange question](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Office_Productivity/Office_Suites/Lotus_SmartSuite/Lotus_Notes/Q_24161449.html)

Comment: I think we can avoid this if we install certificate on the client pc Java control panel trusted certificates. Is there anyway we can automate the process?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do now, and updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully there is no way to suppress the warning, because that would be security bug. If there is such a way, it should be reported and fixed.

---

I'm sorry; I misunderstood the original question, but some of the OP's additional comments have made it clearer. The administrator of the machines in question can automate the setup of a key store with the necessary certificates in it.

See the security information in the [*Java Deployment Guide.*](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/jcp.html#security) Create a key store that contains the certificate used by the developer to sign the application. This will be the "Trusted Certificates" key store, and its location is specified by the "`deployment.system.security.trusted.certs`" property in the deployment properties file (it probably makes most sense to specify this at the system level, rather than the user).

The location of the system properties is [specified in the `deployment.config` file,](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/deployment/deployment-guide/properties.html#dp_system_level) and the location can be a URL so that all workstations point to an enterprise-wide configuration.

Comment: yeah, I was trying to look at the same thing. The easiest way I thought was to install the certificate using keytool.exe. Make a batch file and push it in network along with ton of other applications we install in our systems.

Comment: And Thanks for shedding some light.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can, it's built into Windows. That's one of their built-in mechanisms to prevent infections, etc. That's also why I suspect you can't find the answer.

My question is why wouldn't you want to acquire the certificate? I don't remember the actual costs, but I believe it's somewhere between a hundred and a few hundred to acquire the certificate. Definitely a LOT less than the costs of trying to figure out how to suppress it in the first place...

Comment: Even signed code (as this appears to be) will require confirmation before running.

Comment: Stephane, I didn't get you. "why wouldn't you want to acquire the certificate" Can you explain little more? I think we can shell out few hundred bucks if we can suppress this.